# Using Ethers.js and Metamask SDK in mobile browser

Tags: ethereum, metamask, ethers.js

I'm trying to avoid using Deep Linking from my web app to Metamask mobile app to run my web dapp on the Built-In browser and keep the user on the native browser. In order to do this, I find out that `await web3Modal.connect()` doesn't work as it relays on window.ethereum and it doesn't handles mobile correctly, opening the Metamask App as expected.

In order to do this, I used the `MetaMask SDK` which handles correctly the connection to the Metamask Mobile App.

```
import MetaMaskSDK from '@metamask/sdk';

const MMSDK = new MetaMaskSDK(options);

const ethereum = MMSDK.getProvider();

// This opens the app correctly, ask form permission, and gets back to the browser
ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts', params: [] });
```

My problem is that as I'm using Ethers.js to interact with my Smart Contracts, at some point I need to instantiate the Contract and pass a signer to it, in order to be able to send transactions. However, I can't make Ethers.js work with the `Metamask SDK` provider

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
const signer = provider.getSigner();
```

Anyone has faced the same issue and was able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The SDK is made to have Dapps run outside of the MetaMask in-app browser.

So you run them on your mobile/desktop browser (Chrome/Brave, etc) and you connect with the MM mobile app.

As for Ethers integration, take a look at our [repo in the examples](https://github.com/MetaMask/examples) as some of them have etherjs + SDK running. Your approach looks correct. You can use Ethers if you like and would be similar to any way you have used Ethers in a prior project.

Comment: Even though I made it work, the interaction between web dapp and Metamask mobile app is quiet unstable. It doesn't work properly 100% of the times. Sometimes it opens the app, sometimes it goes to the app store. Other times, it opens the app, but the promt for authorizing the transaction never appears. It seems is still in Beta